# IdentityServer4: SSO across different browsers

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am implementing back-channel logout in IdentityServer4 by specifying the BackChannelLogoutURL.
I have two MVC clients (Razor pages) and if I open both clients in the same browser, SSO works great (i.e. if I logout from client1, back channel for client2 got called by IdentityServer4.

However, the back-channel logout URL doesn't get called if I open the two clients in different browsers. I think this because there are different sessions (Please correct me if I am wrong). Can we initiate logout callback per user regardless of the session?

Comment: are you sure you really want what you are asking about? logout per user will cause logout all their devices, not only the one, initiating the logout. then, I am not aware of any ready solution, but you can implement your own by overriding the session to keep it server side [see my example](https://github.com/dfrunet/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Extensions/ExtendedUserSession.cs) and merging based on the user id.

Comment: Yes this is because of seperate sessions and cookies. You can keep track of the sessions, but then again, why would you? The users have to login in each browser as well, right? So why not keep the logout seperated?

Comment: Basically no. You're right, two browsers two different sessions. And also two different id_tokens (the id_token_hint you provide to the logout endpoint)

Comment: @d_f, I check your code and it gives me a list of sessions associated with a user. How can I issue a logout based on the session?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, My idea is keeping the normal logout as it is but give the user the option to signout all devices.

Comment: when you issue a normal logout, it fetches the list of logged in clients from the session. so if you merge them all by user id, it will trigger the logout request to each. one limitation: IdSrv hosting application' sessions in different browsers will be still there -- you have to handle that separately